# Three.js texture loads in small resolution, same picture scaled up brakes the scene (small image about 600x600px, scaled up to about 1400px)

Tags: three.js, textures, environment

I have a pretty strange behaviour with three.js when I try to load different textures for an environment cube map. Everything works fine till I try to test the same scene with larger textures. My camera is pretty much stable so I only have to change one side of the env cube to a large resolution texture as that will be the background of the scene which will be visible, the other 5 sides are small pngs - those are only visible in reflection.

There is no clear breaking point, what seems to usually work as an image for the env.cube is about 600x600px-ish, going any higher resulting in the scene loading completely black.
To make the scene look nice on most devices, I have to go up to a resolution around 1500x1500px (so not insanely large) for the background, and I have no idea why it breaks with a bigger image.

What I already tried/did:

image paths are fine, overwriting a working image to a larger version also breaks the scene.

I had no other idea what to try, maybe it has to do something with photoshop and its image encoding or something along those lines?

the scene contains:

a camera, a gltf model to test with and the environment cube. everything works perfect with small textures.

I already looked at the texture documentation of threejs and found nothing about what could cause this behaviour, I'm completely stuck.

Comment: the only textures in the scene are the 6 images of the cubemap, 5 images around 5-6kb and one around 400kb

Comment: Does it still work with 1024x1024? BTW: You should always ensure that cube map textures are POT textures.

Comment: Any chance you could show us a working demo of the issue? Either via https://jsfiddle.net/ or in a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Your approach sounds like it should work, so it would help a lot to post the code in question to better see where the issue is.

Comment: @Mugen87 no, it doesn't, I tried 1024, 2048 and weirdly it does not solve the issue either

Comment: @Marquizzo try to change the env cube textures in any of the example scenes to:
var urls = [ 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/px.png', 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/nx.png', 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/py.png', 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/ny.png', 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/pz.png', 'https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/nz.png', ]; this works absolutely fine. change the nz.png to: https://www.adambernath.com/textures/env/background.png breaks it.

Comment: @Marquizzo I have retested it, and it is context independent, changing the cubemap texture to larger images breaks threejs in all cases. (ive retried it with the example pages) try it on this one: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lightprobe.html

I am using version 0.119.1 of threejs, but it seems like, version doesnt matter either.

Comment: That's because all 6 of your images have to be the same dimensions. You can't have one high-Rez and the other 5 low-Rez.

Comment: @Marquizzo oh, I see, that's not something I'm used to from conventional 3d, but I guess I have to play by three js rules, I just wasn't aware of this. I'm a bit sad as wasting resource on images that are barely visible is ...well wasting resources really. thanks anyways!

Comment: You could combine your PNGs with some JPGs, since they can give you very small filesize when there's not a lot of detail.

Comment: @Marquizzo yes, I was thinking about how to go about this problem, in file size i can go low, but the issue here is the loading time of a 2-4k cube with 6 maps - its really slow, in that regard, it doesn't really matter if the source file is a 50kb jpg or a 500kb png :/ 

ive even tried svg, it has its own issues, but thats probably the lowest you can go in file size and keep the best quality, maybe thats the best option, I'm not fully understanding how that is decided what resolution to rasterize at (maybe artboard size or...?)

Comment: @Marquizzo but still, probably even svg won't solve the issue of loading time of 6 2-4k cube map texture (regardless of its origin resolution), I think ive sat in front of an empty screen for like 20 seconds when tried to load a 4k cube

Comment: I've never had to use 4K images for an envmap, it might be overkill for a lot of devices. Why don't you load smaller images on devices based on window height? That way you don't waste all that bandwidth on laptop or cellphone users, you only use super high-Rez on displays that really need it.

Comment: @Marquizzo, yes, you are right, the 4k would only be for retina imacs, (maybe 2k is enough) but anything above 512 loads insanely slow, 256 loads I'd say fairly nicely, 512 okayish, and above that its insanely slow, but 512 is pretty terrible looking on a 4-5k display as you can imagine
My main target audience is designers - mostly imacs at workplaces, so it has to look tack sharp. if I cant get around the image rendering time I'm probably gonna solve it with text from geometry and only showing the background in reflections at a managable size